# DataGrid Paging Problem in IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, datagrid

I have a single templated column in a DataGrid, in an ASP.NET 2 web sites.  The DataGrid is paged, with ten rows per page.

In Firefox, all is good, as nearly always, but when I view the site trough IE, I get the following exception:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.

Any ideas on what may cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this before in relation with dynamically added controls. Outside your DataGrid are you programatically adding controls to your page?

If so ensure that they are constructed, named, and added to the page on the Page's Init event otherwise you can possible gunk up the event tracking, and validation.